# Trying to access controller in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My ultimate goal is to use information from my database to create a line graph using my MVC application. So far I have managed to gather this data using a view model and LINQ queries in my controller and I have made sure the data is accurate by running a test in the view. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to include it in my JavaScript file. In my controller I have a function

```
private DataBase db = new DataBase();
public ActionResult GetInfo() {
    var model = new UserViewModel();
    model.val1=db.table.Where(n=>n.UserID==curUser).Select(n=>n.SomeData).ToArray();
    model.val2=db.table.Where(n=>n.UserID==curUser).Select(n=>n.MoreData).ToArray();
    model.dictionary = the stuff from above;
```

And then in my JavaScript file I'm using Chart.Js to graph a chart. So far it just has fake data to make sure everything was linked up correctly but it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var chart=new CanvasJS.Chart("moodgraph",{
        animationEnabled: false,
        theme: "light2",
        title: {
            text: "Simple Line Chart"
        },
        axisY: {
            includeZero: false
        },
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            indexLabelFontSize: 16,
            dataPoints: [

                { x: 1,y: 450 },
                { y: 414 },
                { y: 520,indexLabel: "\u2191 highest",markerColor: "red",markerType: "triangle" },
                { y: 460 },
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 500 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 410,indexLabel: "\u2193 lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey",markerType: "cross" },
                { y: 500 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 510 }
            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();

});
```

That graph does appear in my view so I know all that is working fine. What I've been struggling with is figuring out how to get that dataPoints to populate with the dictionary values that I grabbed in my controller... So far I tried using

```
var model=@Model.Dictionary
```

to access the information but that threw an error. And then I've struggled with trying to return an object in the controller but that messes with code that I can't touch as someone else wrote it for this project. I know I'm missing one simple piece but my Google searches don't show me how to do this in the strict parameters I'm stuck with in this project.

How do I access the view model data in my separate JavaScript file?

Comment: How are you passing the data from the controller to the view, are you using like `ViewBag`, once you are using like a viewbag, it is easy to get the view set it to a js variable and then use it within javascript.

Comment: also, what error do you get while calling the `var model=@Model.Dictionary` assuming that you are passing the data to the view using a typed view

Comment: `@Model.Dictionary` will not access a property named `dictionary` on the `Model`. C# is case sensitive. Please include the error you are getting.

Comment: @Saravanan There is no need to use `ViewBag`, since the data are already on `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

1 - In your controller :

```
*
*
ViewBag.Dico = model.dictionary;
return View("chartPage");
```

2 - in your chartPage.cshtml (or declare your variable globally 'Layout.cshtml'):

```
<script> 
   var myPoints= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Dico));
</script>
```

3 - in ChartJs:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var chart=new CanvasJS.Chart("moodgraph",{
        *
        *
        *
        },
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            indexLabelFontSize: 16,
            dataPoints: (typeof(myPoints) != "undefined" ? myPoints: [])
        }]
    });
    chart.render();

});
```

Comment: There is no need to use `ViewBag`, since the data are already on `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

using Chart.JS library you can make dynamic charts from the database data by following the next steps

**Model:**
suppose you have model for graph data as following:

```
  public class JsResultChart
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; } 
    }
```

---

**Controller:**

return your data from the controller (using model, viewbag..etc) as list

```
var JsResultChart= new List<JsResultChart> 
{
new JsResultChart{ Name ="first", Value = 100 }, //data will be fetched from db
new JsResultChart{ Name ="second", Value = 200 },
};
Model.JsResultChart = JsResultChart;
```

---

**View:**
add something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="hidden" id="Lables" name="Lables" value="@Json.Encode(Model.ChartData.Select(x => x.Name).ToList())" />
        <input type="hidden" id="Values" name="Values" value="@Json.Encode(Model.ChartData.Select(x => x.Value).ToList())">
        <canvas id="myChart" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="NotPrintable"></canvas>
        <div id="ResultsDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**javascript:**

```
var Names = $("#Lavels").val();
var Numbers = $("#Values").val();
Names = JSON.parse(Names);
Numbers = JSON.parse(Numbers);
       
var data = {
    labels: Names,
    datasets: [{
        fill: false,
        data: Numbers,
        label: "Value" //you can write(label: Names) rather than (label: "Value")
    }]
};

var ctx = $("#myChart");
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options //add your options
});
```